# how to extrac parse href,src,alt using xpath

Tags: php

i need to find the image link and a href . show href,img src, and alt tag.

here my code

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath('http,://.....');


foreach ($xpath->query('//a[@href]//img') as $img) {


echo '<a href=' .'"' .$img['href'] .'"' .'/>' .'<img src="' .$img['src']    .'"' .'alt="' .$img['alt'] .'"/>' .'</a>';



Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an     
instance of DOMDocument, string given, called in
```

Can you help me??

Comment: load `DOMDocument` first, then use `DOMXpath` you can't just dump the url directly

Comment: For reference: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

then use xpath to do whatever you want to do with it

**Edited to get image src from link**

```
# get the images inside a link
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[@href]//img') as $img) {

    # find all the links and images       
    for ($link = $img; $link->tagName !== 'a'; $link = $link->parentNode);

    $output[] = array(
        'href' => $link->getAttribute('href'),
        'src'  => $img->getAttribute('src'),
        'alt'  => $img->getAttribute('alt'),
    );
}
```

Comment: blank , i can't show  
echo '<a href=' .'"' .$img['href'] .'"' .'/>' .'<img src="' .$img['src']    .'"' .'alt="' .$img['alt'] .'"/>' .'</a>';

Comment: modified my answer to fit your requirement, I think the responce is too late, but it may help someone else